# Sampling raster by line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, line, sampling

I am quite new to GIS, and was wondering if you might be able to help me out?

I have a raster layer for gradient as well as a line created from GPS tracking points(using the point connector tool). Is there a way to sample the raster layer according to the distance covered along each raster value by the line?

Comment: Hi Rob, welcome to the site/GIS. Can you state what software you want/need to use for this? Can you also clarify: do you want the raster sampled at each GPS point or do you want the raster sampled at a regular interval along your line?

Answer (score 1):

MikeRSpencer's comment is the key to choose the best method among possible options QGIS can offer.

1. Sample at each GPS point
2. Sample at a regular interval along the line

Without additional information from OP (well...not yet), remaining option would be:

3. Sample **all the cells** along the line

In QGIS Processing Toolbox, there is a SAGA Tool **Profiles from lines** (in `SAGA | Terrain Analysis - Profiles`).

[image]

The output table shows 1 record (row) per each cell on which the line overlays. Depend on how we want to sample out from this table, we can use `DIST` (distance from the start point) or `X,Y` coordinates to refer the location.

Positive point is that we can choose sampling method afterwords. Negative point is the data size, unnecessarily large, if we have already decided how we want to measure the profile.